# Video editor for android - FFmpeg won't compile on windows?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, ffmpeg, boot

Im trying to make a video editor for android (I've never made an android app before)

After searching for libraries to use I came across FFmpeg but I'm having trouble getting it to compile on Windows 7.

I'm currently using Eclipse and have the most recent android SDK and ndk.

I've been trying to follow tutorials on the internet including roman10's (http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-ndk-r9/) but they all seem specific to Linux.

Yesterday, I thought I'd give up and just dual boot Ubuntu on my windows laptop but of course that was messing up too. I shrank my partition and booted Ubuntu of a USB but the installer was detecting there is no OS on my laptop and not giving me the option to install it alongside windows 7.

So, can FFmpeg be compiled for android on windows? Or is there another library I could use to make a video editor that can?

Or should I just persist with dual booting ubuntu?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have already know that on Windows you must use Cygwin. This is open source tools which provide functionality similar to a Linux distribution on Windows. 
I work with ndk in linux. It avoids  many problems and errors which i can found in Windows.
Here link how to start work with Cygwin:
http://mindtherobot.com/blog/452/android-beginners-ndk-setup-step-by-step/

Comment: Thanks. I actually ended up dual booting ubuntu and compiling it on that. I managed  get it to compile using the tutorial I stated but I'm confused as to how make it available to use for my android project in eclipse. I've created an Android.mk file and copied over the libraries to the libs folder but it doesn't seem t be working. Do by any chance have suggestions?